# c# Nhibernate Session InstancePerLifetimeScope()

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session

if i register my nhibernate session like this :

builder.Register(i => DI.Get().BeginUnitOfWork()).As().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

now i want the session to re-open every time i open a form.
i wish somebody could help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go through this link to check how an MVP build application manages NHibernate sessions:

[Building a Desktop To-Do Application with NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx)

What you need is basically to handle session per your form / presenter. That is the optimal session scope for desktop applications.